# Are there some pre-trained LSTM, RNN or ANN models for time-series prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to solve a time series prediction problem. I tried with ANN and LSTM,  played around a lot with the various parameters, but all I could get was 8% better than the persistence prediction.

So I was wondering: since you can save models in keras; are there any pre-trained model (LSTM, RNN, or any other ANN) for time series prediction? If so, how to I get them? Are there in Keras?

I mean it would be super useful if there a website containing pre trained models, so that people wouldn't have to speent too much time training them..

Similarly, another question:

Is it possible to do the following?
1. Suppose I have a dataset now and I use it to train my model. Suppose that in a month, I will have access to another dataset (corresponding to same data or similar data, in the future possibly, but not exclusively). Will it be possible to continue training the model then? It is not the same thing as training it in batches. When you do it in batches you have all the data in one moment. 
Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 14):

I'll answer your last questions first.

> Will it be possible to continue training the model then? It is not the same thing as training it in batches. When you do it in batches you have all the data in one moment. Is it possible? And how?

Yes, it is possible. In general, it's called [transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning). But keep in mind that if two datasets represent very different populations, the network will soon "forget" what it learned on the first run and will optimize to the second one. To do this, you simply start training from a [loaded state](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) instead of random initialization and save the model afterwards. It is also recommended to use a smaller learning rate on the second run in order to adapt it gradually to the new data.

> are there any pre-trained model (LSTM, RNN, or any other ANN) for time
>   series prediction? If so, how to I get them? Are there in Keras?

I haven't found exactly a *pre-trained* model, but a quick search gave me several active GitHub projects that you can just run and get a result for yourself: [Time Series Prediction with Machine Learning](https://github.com/maxim5/time-series-machine-learning) (LSTM, GRU implementation in tensorflow), [LSTM Neural Network for Time Series Prediction](https://github.com/jaungiers/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction) (keras and tensorflow), [Time series predictions with Keras](https://github.com/gcarq/keras-timeseries-prediction) (keras and theano), [Neural-Network-with-Financial-Time-Series-Data](https://github.com/BenjiKCF/Neural-Network-with-Financial-Time-Series-Data) (keras and tensorflow). See also [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/).

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use BERT or related variants and here you can find all the pre-trained models: https://huggingface.co/transformers/pretrained_models.html

And it is possible to pre-train and fine-tune RNN, and you can refer to this paper: [TimeNet: Pre-trained deep recurrent neural network for time series classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08838.pdf).